# VBScript converitng .xlsx files to .csv

Tags: vbscript

I have the script that does a perfect job of converting excel .xlsx files to .csv files.

```
Dim fso: set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

CurrentDirectory = fso.GetAbsolutePathName(".")

Set folder = fso.GetFolder(CurrentDirectory)

For each file In folder.Files

If fso.GetExtensionName(file) = "xlsx" Then

pathOut = fso.BuildPath(CurrentDirectory, fso.GetBaseName(file)+".csv")

    Dim oExcel
    Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Dim oBook
    Set oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(file)
    oBook.SaveAs pathOut, 6
    oBook.Close False
    oExcel.Quit
 End If
 Next
```

I want to understand how it works and I am not sure about this line:

`oBook.SaveAs pathOut, 6`

Is **6** some type of a constant? 
If so - can you refer me to documentation/ online resources to learn about the full list? I had no luck googling myself.

Thanks!

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198017.aspx

Comment: JNevill, thank a lot!

Comment: And for those "super-friendly"  people voting the question down: I am an Accountant....yes, i didn't know the key words to google the answer...hope you get the same treatment from my colleagues if you ever have to ask a tax related question :)

Comment: A google search of "saveas vba" brings you to the MSDN page for the workbook method. If you have a vbscript related question, MSDN is the right resource. The first hit lists the requirements for each parameter, wherein you will find a link to the xlFileFormat enumeration page that I linked above. As for the fake internet points, you'll be fine. I pick up a down vote at least once a week. Their like little badges of honor.

Comment: Thanks again, JNevil, very helpful... I just joking about the votes :)

Answer (score 0):

Name    Value   Description Extension
xlAddIn 18  Microsoft Excel 97-2003 Add-In  *.xla
xlAddIn8    18  Microsoft Excel 97-2003 Add-In  *.xla
xlCSV   6   CSV *.csv

6 is a format for .csv

for more you could refer
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlfileformat